# Enhancing the pipeline's content?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Let's assume that you have a command that compresses files using 7-zip that accepts values from the pipeline:

```
Function New-Archive {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)][Alias('FullName')]
        [string[]]$Files,

        [string]$Archive='Archive.zip'
    )

    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS {
      Foreach ($File in $Files) {
        & 7z a -tZIP $Archive $File
      }
    }
    END {}
}
```

Assuming the `foo` directory has these files: a.txt, b.txt, c.txt

Executing the command:

```
PS Foo> GCI | New-Archive
```

produces output is something like:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Scanning

Updating archive .\files.zip

Compressing  a.txt
Compressing  b.txt
Compressing  c.txt
Compressing  files.zip

Everything is Ok
```

It's easy enough to parse the output, capture the results of the compression, and add it to the pipeline:

```
...
$output = & 7z a $Archive $File

#
# parse stdout; capture files that were compressed; convert to PsObject[] 
#
$output = $output[7..($output.Length-4)]
$output | foreach {
  $parts = $_ -split "\s+", 2
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Name = $parts[1]
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Should the pipeline include the original content (from `GCI`), the modified content (from `7a`), or both?
2. If both, how is this done?
3. Should the path of resulting file (Archive.zip) be added to the pipeline, or returned by the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Updating archive .\files.zip ... Compressing  files.zip` ? Check if your function has a case when adding `Archive.zip` to `Archive.zip`, this should throw a warning like copying over itself.

About pipeline - I think you should employ `-passthru` switch, if the switch is present, return the archive as a `Get-Item` result (`System.IO.FileInfo` object), otherwise return void. Also, if you'd use `-AsJob` flag, return the job as the function result.

On a side note, if you plan to work with archives in your 7zip module, you need links to them, probably as a subtype of generic file, or just files, and since `New-Archive` is producing one archive and not a set of them, piping seems redundant for this function.

Summary:

1. In this case, modified content or void.
2. No "both".
3. Returning a `System.IO.FileInfo` object will solve both goals.
4. Consider adding a `-LogFile` parameter that would indicate where to put text data from 7zip.

Comment: So, if someone wanted to compress the files, then do something else with the original items in the pipeline, perhaps a `Tee-Object` should be placed between `GCI` and `New-Archive`?

Comment: @craig I think using `-PipelineVariable` on the `GCI` would be better than a Tee-Object

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit subjective, but I would say that:

1. Re-throw any exceptions raised (or use Write-Error) in case of failure
2. Don't produce output unless it makes sense or is requested
3. Parse the output and return proper objects, not just output strings from the executable you wrap

In your example I would probably add a `[Switch]$PassThru` parameter and return a FileInfo object for `Archive.zip`: `Write-Output $(Get-Item $Archive)` if present

Comment: So, do #3 in the `END {}` block?

Comment: Yes, the `end` block executes after all the `process` blocks are finished executing, so that's definitely the place to put the output statement.